# Why won't my Joomla template load correctly in IE9 on Windows 7 / Vista?

Tags: css, windows, joomla, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

We built a Joomla website for one of our clients which can be located at:

http://mayslakeministries.org/

Although everything was looking fine from our end, the client was seeing the website as if no CSS was being rendered. Unfortunately, I do not have a screenshot at the moment. I will try and get one up here in the next hour or so if we don't come up with a resolution. (If anyone is able to see the mess that I'm describing, if you could post a screenshot that would be appreciated as well. We have limited testing equipment available and it's hard for us to reproduce.)

But here is what we've concluded: the website works fine in Chrome and Firefox on all systems. It works fine with IE10 on all systems as well. However, as soon you switch to IE9, things get strange.

IE9 will work fine if you are on Windows 8, but if you are viewing in IE9 from Windows 7 or Vista, things look as if the CSS isn't being loaded.

Any help would be appreciated. If you view the site and find that the information I've provided contradicts what you are seeing, then let me know. We have limited equipment to test with, so it was difficult for us to be able to see the problem.

This is the first time I've encountered a problem that only occurs on a certain OS.

Oh! One more thing I think is worth mentioning. The Joomla template we are using works fine even on Windows 7 IE9. So we believe it's something that we have done to the website that changed it's behavior.

Here is the Joomla template demo:

http://www.astemplates.com/itempreview/186

Comment: They might have needed to do a simply forced refresh (CTRL + F5)

Comment: We checked and it's not a caching issue. Any other ideas?

Comment: hmm, if it's happening specifically in windows 7 and IE9 for the client, maybe suggest reinstalling IE9 to see if this solves the problem. I have never known a site to have CSS issues on a specific OS

Comment: Thanks for your response. We were indeed able to reproduce it in the office on our Windows 7 machine, and again on our Vista machine, so the problem isn't something that is the fault of the client. It's a real frustrating problem because we're really not sure how to go about fixing it.

Comment: Might have to do with the three `link` tags that come before the `head` tag...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, it took is a few days, but we finally figured out the problem.

IE apparently has a limit to the number of resources that can be linked to the page at one time. Our Joomla site has around 200 JS/CSS files being linked through the source, and this caused IE to bug out and not load our CSS properly.

This is one of the strangest problems I've had to deal with, so I'm very glad it's fixed.